# Get value of a cookie for login test in Selenium + Java

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, authentication

So, I am doing tests of "Login using cookies" for a website I am working on. I tried to use the method: getValue() to get the value of a named cookie (which holds the info for a user). But the problem is, because the cookie which holds this info, only appears (in Application menu [in F12]). After completing the login process, I keep getting "nullPointerExeption". So my question is this: is there a way to get the cookie's value 
before the login process and use it in order to log in?

The method for get value:

```
public static String getCookieValueFromWebPage(String cookieName){

    String value = remoteWebDriver.manage().getCookieNamed(cookieName).getValue();
    return value;
}
```

Comment: First, you need to log in and save your cookies. Second, open the site and load your pre-saved cookies. As result, you should be logged in.

Comment: I can share my working code in Python for Facebook: https://github.com/ratmirasanov/demo_test_automation_project/tree/master/login_with_using_cookies

Comment: You can translate it into Java.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov Thanks for your answer! is there online translator? I tried but didn't find one...

Comment: I don't know about the translator.